# Errors trying to install diskusage node_module

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I've been trying to install the `diskusage` node_module and I keep getting errors. I've followed links and have come up with nothing.

Here is the result after running `npm install diskusage`:

```
C:\...\project>npm install diskusage
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\diskusage
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.13.0 found at "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2015 as it is only supported up to Node.js 18
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:380:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2015 (C:\Users\user\Documents\github\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:364:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:67:12
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at failPowershell (C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:156:7)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.parseData (C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:170:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:143:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:414:7)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\diskusage
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

My project is a `nodejs` express project that has run in vscode before. I'm doing a reinstall and now it's asking where Visual Studio is.

I don't know how to fix those errors.

**Regarding installing Visual Studio to fix the issues**:
Installing Desktop Development with C++ workload
[image]

**UPDATE:**
Installed Visual Studio and that got rid of one error message and now I'm getting this error in the console:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\project> npm install diskusage                          
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\diskusage               
npm ERR! command failed                                                                                       
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild                                        
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok                                                                
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.13.0 found at "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.9.34714.143) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\project\\node_modules\\diskusage\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.11.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.11.1',   
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\project\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\20.11.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\project\\node_modules\\diskusage',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\project\\node_modules\\diskusage\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 42, in <module>
npm ERR!     import gyp  # noqa: E402
npm ERR!     ^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
npm ERR!     import gyp.input
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 19, in <module>
npm ERR!     from distutils.version import StrictVersion
npm ERR! ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:325:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\diskusage       
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

What the f going on? Why is this giving me so much trouble? This isn't the first error. First python, then directory can't be removed, then command failed, then install visual studio, then missing module diskutils. Why is this library giving me so much trouble (update it's not just this library)? Isn't npm supposed to handle all of this? Shouldn't npm install the things it needs to function? If you run an npm installer and then npm fails more than 4 times asking where missing items are when trying to install a library then is it installed?

If this is related to the [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diskusage) itself, and this is the normal install process, how can I avoid node modules like this?

Maybe on the npmjs.com site the library should say "must be compiled from source" and so it "needs visual studio" installed or "needs python installed".

**Solution Update:**
I downgraded to Python 3.11 because it was mentioned that the tools / commands mentioned in the errors above were removed from newer versions of python and then I also opened a terminal window (not in vscode but a cmd / powershell and ran as administrator) and then ran `npm install diskusage` and the error has gone away and everything seems to be in order.

I don't know what action fixed the issue because I did two things at once. I'm guessing both were needed (to remove the can't remove directory) and the python install errors of can't install because of missing commands.

Comment: The log you're showing is literally telling you the problem: `Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use`. You installed something that needs to be compiled from source, and you don't have the tool chain for that installed. See https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp?tab=readme-ov-file#on-windows

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans what needs to be compiled from source? I haven't seen that message before. If a library wants to be compiled from C++ then I need to uninstall it. It's a nodejs project. I don't want to install Visual Studio at this time.

Comment: ... the... `diskusage` package? The one you're showing as being the package you're installing at the top of the log you're showing?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/diskusage?activeTab=readme wants me to compile from source and it wants to use visual studio to do that? ...if that's the case that sort of defeats the purpose of importing a ready to use library. i could install visual studio but i could also try and find an alternative node module

Comment: Yes, no, and not really, respectively. Yes it wants to compile the Windows-specific parts from source, because it needs to. No, you don't need Visual Studio, you just need the compiler and headers so that you can build things on Windows. And no it doesn't, every unix/linux comes with build tools, on MacOS it's literally one command in the terminal to install the build tool chain, and on Windows it's "install the Visual Studio installer, and then tell it to only install the build tools".

Comment: I just did, in a clean directory: `npm init -y` `npm install diskusage` and it was fine.  So maybe try deleting your `node_modules` folder and your `package-lock.json` and then doing `npm install` again.

Comment: @Wyck it depends entirely on whether there's a precompiled binary for your exact version of OS and the version of Node.js you're using. If there is no precompiled binary, no amount of clearing node_modules will do anything.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans judging by the Windows_NT 10.0.22000 we're on the same system.  I also used the same node version.  Most curious detail of the steps to reproduce (which clearly do *not* reproduce for me) is _"I'm doing a reinstall"_.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans makes sense. if I'll need Visual Studio build tools in the future it sounds like it would be a good idea to install it.

Comment: A ton of Node modules with OS specific components will need it, so you generally make your life a lot easier by just installing the build-components-only part of VSC++ as explained on https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp?tab=readme-ov-file#on-windows. It's just one of those things that comes with doing Node development on Windows (same goes for MacOS, step one's pretty much running `xcode-select --install`)

Comment: OK more clues. It looks like diskusage needs node gyp and node gyp needs visual studio... From the linked page, "Installation. You can install node-gyp using npm: npm install -g node-gyp. Depending on your operating system, you will need to install: Visual Studio"

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans when I deploy to *nix, a remote server, `diskusage` seems to work. how can that be if it has to be compiled? do you know if *nix comes with it preinstalled? actually the logs sometimes or maybe always say the same thing, `command failed`, but in the nodejs app the calls seem to work

Comment: Presumably diskusage can just tap directly into a literal million preinstalled dedicated commands to get the information it needs on unix/linux. Windows has nowhere near the same amount of utility commands available.

Comment: I installed Visual Studio, ran `npm install diskusage` and now I'm getting another error (added above). It's error after error with this. First python, then directory can't be removed, then command failed, then diskutils. Why is this library giving me so much trouble? Isn't npm supposed to handle all of this?

Comment: I downgraded to Python 3.11 and then I also opened a second terminal window (cmd powershell and ran as admin) and ran `npm install diskusage` and the error has gone away and everything seems to be in order. I don't know what action fixed the issue because I did two things at once. I'm guessing both were needed (to remove the can't remove directory) and the can't install because of missing modules.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `diskusage` package needs some extra tools to install itself. I assume that it needs Visual Studio.

Either install the Full Monty (Visual Studio). This is what the error message recommends. It will give you everything you need for `diskusage` and other development projects. You can download it from the official Microsoft website.

Go Lighter (Build Tools for Visual Studio). If you don't want the whole shebang of Visual Studio, you can just grab the "Build Tools" part. This has the necessary bits of `diskusage` needs. You can find these tools on the same Microsoft download page.

Once you've got either of those installed, just run the `npm install diskusage` command again and it should find the missing pieces and install happily.

Before that, try to double-check that your Node.js version works with `diskusage`. You can find compatibility info in the `diskusage` documentation (usually online).

If things still go wrong after installing Visual Studio stuff, try adding the `--loglevel silly flag` to the `npm install diskusage` command. This gives you more detailed error messages that might help troubleshoot further.

This should help you to get `diskusage` up and running in no time.